# How to read ALL logs of a certain event

Tags: events, logs

When I read `event logs` like this:

```
myContract.getPastEvents('myEventLogName', {
    fromBlock: 0,
    toBlock: 'latest'
})
.then(function(events){
    console.log(events) // same results as the optional callback above
});
```

I get the following message at the end:

> ... 8 more items ]

How can I read really **ALL** `event logs`?

Comment: That sounds more like a JS truncation. Try looping over the result array and printing each event individually

Comment: `event` and `log` are the same thing. Explorer's call them events, EVM calls them logs.